# JavaScript function Not Working with onchange attribute of input tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have been trying to replicate Duncan Donut Example from `HEAD FIRST JAVASCRIPT`, but the function `subTotal()` is never triggered by onchange event and when I look into [HTML REFERENCE](https://htmlref.com/reference/appa/tag_input.htm), I did not find any onchange event in list provided.

**Duncan.html**

```
    <html>
    <head><title>Duncan Online Donut's Service</title></head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function subTotal(){
            document.write("working");
            const TAXRATE = 0.095;
            const DONUTRATE = 0.5;
            var tax = 0;
            var subTotal = 0;
            var total = 0;
            var cakedonut = parseInt(document.getElementById("cakedonut").value);
            var glazedonut = parseInt(document.getElementById("glazedonut").value);

            if(isNaN(cakedonut))
                cakedonut = 0;
            if(isNaN(glazedonut))
                glazedounut = 0;

            subTotal = (cakedonut + glazedonut)* DONUTRATE ;
            tax = subTotal * TAXRATE ;
            total = subTotal + tax ;
            document.getElementById("subTotal").value = "$" + subTotal.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("tax").value = "$" + tax.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);    
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <h1><b><i>Duncan Online Donut's Service</i></b></h1>
        <form>
            Name : <input id="name" type="text" name="name"/><br><br>
            #no of cake donuts : <input id="cakedonut" type="text" name="cakedonut" onchange="subTotal()"/><br><br>
            #no of glazed donuts : <input id="glazedonut" type="text" name="glazedonut" onchange="subTotal("/><br><br>
            subTotal : <input id="subTotal" type="text" name="subTotal" /><br><br>
            tax : <input id="tax" type="text" name="tax" /><br><br>
            Total : <input id="total" type="text" name="total"/><br><br>
            <input type="submit"/><br><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o6vhzfcy/1/)

The above is my code. I tried running this on `IE and Chrome` but in vain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cattla It did not work.

Comment: First observation. #no of glazed donuts : <input id="glazedonut" type="text" name="glazedonut" onchange="subTotal("/><br><br>  - Closing brace is missing. Investigation is on :)

Comment: change your function name. don't use subTotal();

Comment: @Diptendu I did add the parenthesis still its not working.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said the investigation is on :)

Comment: The comment by @Cattla is correct. You also have a `document.write()` call in there which will overwrite the contents of the html page, causing the rest of the function to fail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you have defined a variable and a function both with the same name `subTotal` and the variable declaration is overriding the function definition. Change the function name to anything say `subTotal1` it will work.

[JSBIN link](https://jsbin.com/qakokiyito/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

change your function name. don't use `subTotal();` and don't use `document.write("working");`

```
function subTotalnew()
{
alert('working');
}
```

`onchange="subTotalnew()` it gonna be work after input `blur`.

`oninput="subTotalnew()` it gonna be work when input `entering something`.